# What does string.IndexOf do?

Tags: c#

I'm working through string manipulation, where I need to find characters or copy some part of the string that the user has input and divide it to 3 different areas. I'm not asking anything here about code, I'll do it myself, but I was searching in the documentation that Microsoft provide about the IndexOf method and its 8 overloads and I can't really understand how to apply it. I simply can't understand what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Did you try reading the [MSDN page for `String.IndexOf()` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx), and especially the description of the various overloads? What part _specifically_ don't you understand?

Comment: `"i simply can't understand what it is supposed to do"` - The `string.IndexOf()` method?  It looks for the first occurrence of a given character/string in the string on which it's invoked and returns the index of that occurrence (the index of the first character in the string as an array of characters).

Comment: The answer of @cFrozenDeath kind of explained me what i wanted , i did read it , yet i couldnt understand what was there , what was explaned here was much more let me say " understanding"

Comment: @MiguelBastos if your question is answered, please remember to mark the accepted answer so we all win :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the MSDN explanation is pretty clear.

For example:

```
string something = "something";
int indexOfT = something.IndexOf("t"); // => returns 4
```

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance.

So if "t" is in the fifth position of "something", 4 would be it's zero-based index.

Comment: RIght , what really means the zero-based index ? that the counter starts at 0 ?

Comment: @MiguelBastos exactly. Instead of starting the count as 1 as you would normally do, it starts at 0.

Comment: Right , thank you for the example and the edit  ^^

Comment: @MiguelBastos it's a pleasure to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Returns the first appearance of a specified char.
For example

```
string x = "Hello World";

x.indexOf("W");
```

it will return 6 (0 based count).

The overloads let you choose for example, where you want to start searching.. like

`x.indexOf("W", 7);` it will return -1 because W is at position 6 so if starts at 7 it won't find any.

I hope this helps ! the best way is to play with it

This also works with arrays.

Comment: Thank you , understood it now ^^ , and for example if i try to find the one comma in the array and "copy" what was behind it to somewhere else , how can i extract it ? substring ?

Comment: `string x = "Hello,World";`
`x.substring(0, x.indexOf(','));` this will start at position 0 and stop at the char position, returning the string in between.